# Pattern to extract, expand and form a sentence based on a certain delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I was trying out to solve a problem on regex:

There is an input sentence which is of one of these forms: `Number1,2,3` or `Number1/2/3` or `Number1-2-3` these are the 3 delimiters: `,` `/` `-`

The expected output is: `Number1,Number2,Number3`

Pattern I've tried so far:

`(?\<=,)\[^,\]+(?=,)`

but this misses out on the edge cases i.e. 1st element and last element. I am also not able to generate for '/'.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate out the key from values, then use a list comprehension to build the output you want.

```py
inp = "Number1,2,3"
matches = re.search(r'(\D+)(.*)', inp)
output = [matches[1] + x for x in re.split(r'[,/]', matches[2])]
print(output)  # ['Number1', 'Number2', 'Number3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several steps: 1) validate the string to match your pattern, and once validated 2) add the first non-digit chunk to the numbers while replacing `-` and `/` separator chars with commas:

```py
import re
texts = ['Number1,2,3', 'Number1/2/3', 'Number1-2-3']
for text in texts:
    m = re.search(r'^(\D+)(\d+(?=([,/-]))(?:\3\d+)*)$', text)
    if m:
        print( re.sub(r'(?<=,)(?=\d)', m.group(1).replace('\\', '\\\\'), text.replace('/',',').replace('-',',')) )
    else:
        print(f"NO MATCH in '{text}'")
```

See [this Python demo](http://waw-msedu/TermCenter/Default.aspx).

Output:

```
Number1,Number2,Number3
Number1,Number2,Number3
Number1,Number2,Number3
```

The `^(\D+)(\d+(?=([,/-]))(?:\3\d+)*)$` regex validates your three types of input:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\D+)` - Group 1: one or more non-digits
- `(\d+(?=([,/-]))(?:\3\d+)*)` - Group 2: one or more digits, and then zero or more repetitions of `,`, `/` or `-` and one or more digits (and the separator chars should be consistent due to the capture used in the positive lookahead and the `\3` backreference to that value used in the non-capturing group)
- `$` - end of string.

The `re.sub` pattern, `(?<=,)(?=\d)`, matches a location between a comma and a digit, the Group 1 value is placed there (note the `.replace('\\', '\\\\')` is necessary since the replacement is dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

for text in ("Number1,2,3", "Number1-2-3", "Number1/2/3"):
  print(re.sub(r"(\D+)(\d+)[/,-](\d+)[/,-](\d+)", r"\1\2,\1\3,\1\4", text))
```

- `\D+` matches "Number" or any other non-number text
- `\d+` matches a number (or more than one)
- `[/,-]` matches any of `/`, `,`, `-`

The rest is copy paste 3 times.

The substitution consists of backreferences to the matched "Number" string (`\1`) and then each group of the `(\d+)`s.

This works if you're sure that it's always three numbers divided by that separator. This does not ensure that it's the same separator between each number. But it's short.

Output:

```
Number1,Number2,Number3
Number1,Number2,Number3
Number1,Number2,Number3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make use of the [pypi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) you can use the captures collection with a named capture group.

```
([^\d\s,/]+)(?<num>\d+)([,/-])(?<num>\d+)(?:\3(?<num>\d+))*(?!\S)
```

- `([^\d\s,/]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ chars other than the listed
- `(?<num>\d+)` Named capture group *num* matching 1+ digits
- `([,/-])` Capture either `,` `/` `-` in group 3
- `(?<num>\d+)` Named capture group *num* matching 1+ digits
- `(?:\3(?<num>\d+))*` Optionally repeat a backreference to group 3 to keep the separators the same and match 1+ digits in group *num*
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitspace boundary to the right to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/An80yp/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##VY7NTsMwEITvforFl9rUxArht6LkDbhwTFLkJm5rJP9os5Hg6YMjcoA9zax2vp30TZcYqnl2PkUkQHu2X2DGLBhLhshigD0gF82hHdpR6W4rRf0SJv/aDlk2St90/zb1rq3@eHkt6qv2XXI2ZhB/m/zRYqluVQUR4dfe6Xv9AMeJIERad4/6ST1zxryh/mKXLNri5MLgciexVlMwSnbKnA8FHlwAm99aNGTFmssXZJD2pdwxyJPQBRIbtSk@owui8cUZ45REKWELPSysfgH5ojeJJrSj4JnJZSflPP8A)

```
import regex as re

pattern = r"([^\d\s,/]+)(?<num>\d+)([,/-])(?<num>\d+)(?:\3(?<num>\d+))*(?!\S)"
s = "Number1,2,3 or Number4/5/6 but not Number7/8,9"

matches = re.finditer(pattern, s)
for _, m in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print(','.join([m.group(1) + c for c in m.captures("num")]))
```

Output

```
Number1,Number2,Number3
Number4,Number5,Number6
```

Comment: Hi, does it not fail if there are numbers in the first part, some input like: Numb3r1,2,3
The output is r1,r2,r3. Whereas expected is Numb3r3,Numb3r2,Numb3r3

Comment: @theboy In that case you can also accept numbers `([^\s,/]+)(?<num>\d+)([,/-])(?<num>\d+)(?:\2(?<num>\d+))*(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/yQpmtS/1 Or make it non greedy `([^\s,/]+?)(?<num>\d+)([,/-])(?<num>\d+)(?:\2(?<num>\d+))*(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/7czkCt/1